How to make hierarchical bookmarks in emacs?
I'm looking for an emacs package that allows me to manually draw a tree view of my bookmarks.
A bookmark can be a child or sibling of another bookmark.
Kind of like a call tree, but all items are added manually.
I am aware of emacs' built-in bookmark.el.
But it clearly doesn't support hierarchical structures.
I did a Vim plugin earlier to do the job. Here's what it looks like:


If you use Bookmark+ then you can construct a hierarchy of bookmarks using bookmark tags.
You need only define your tags in such a way that they implement a hierarchy. I don't know exactly what you'd want for that, but you could, for example, use tags such as these:

controller
controller/A controller
controller/A controller/A1 controller
controller/A controller/A2 controller
controller/B controller
controller/B controller/B1 controller
controller/B controller/B2 controller

IOW, you define your own "naming" system for the categories you want.
You can search, sort, etc. using combinations of tags (union, intersection) and regexp matches.
Bookmark+ doesn't assume any particular system for categorizing/organizing bookmarks - it's up to you what systems you define and use. Bookmark+ also doesn't produce any particular visual representation (e.g. a tree display) that might correspond to one or more such systems.
You can also have tags that are not just strings (names) but that also have associated Lisp values (any Lisp objects, but if you want them persisted and read then they need to be readable).

Go through the source code of a complex project, and that's what I want to do with this plugin. Thanks for your answer.
